# Widget is not updating after JSON parse

Tags: java, android, json

I have the following code:

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);

        if (CLOCK_WIDGET_UPDATE.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "onReceiver()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        new GetJSON().execute(null, null, null);
    }
    public class GetJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
         @Override
         protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) { //Running in background
             try {
                 httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
                 HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://pagesbyz.com/hadith.json");
                 // Depends on your web service
                 httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);           
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                inputStream = entity.getContent();
                // json is UTF-8 by default
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
                sb = new StringBuilder();

                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                result = sb.toString();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.i("TEST", e.toString());
                // Oops
            }
            finally {
                try{if(inputStream != null)inputStream.close();}catch(Exception squish){}
            }
            return null;
         }

         @Override
         protected  void onPreExecute() { //Activity is on progress
         }

         @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {
             try {
                 jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
                 date = new String[jsonArray.length()];
                 quote = new String[jsonArray.length()];
                 by = new String[jsonArray.length()];
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i);
                        date[i] = jsonObj.getString("Date");
                        quote[i] = jsonObj.getString("Quote");
                        by[i] = jsonObj.getString("By");
                    } // End the for loop
                    views.setTextViewText(R.id.tvToday, date[0]);
                    views.setTextViewText(R.id.tvParkStatus, quote[0]);
             }
             catch (JSONException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
        }
    }
```

I am looking to update the widget with the information received from the JSON file. I see the widget but no information is being displayed.

My JSON looks like:

```
[
    {   
        "Date" : "11182013",
        "Quote" : "Today Is Monday",
        "By" : "SiKni8"
    },
    {   
        "Date" : "11192013",
        "Quote" : "Today Is Tuesday",
        "By" : "SiKni8"
    }
]
```

Comment: Check if date[0], quote[0], and by[0] are set to the correct values. Also you may have to update your UI to see the change. edit: I found an answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4433464/settextviewtext-not-updating-widget

Comment: I should call `appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);` I am thinking but it can be called only from `onUpdate()` method.

Comment: I saw that line in another answer but where should I add it? inside the `onPostExecute`?

Answer (score 1):

Change your AsynkTast to:

```
public class GetJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

     @Override
     protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) { //Running in background

     // ...
     // do all your stuff as it is and change return to this :

     return result;
     }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) { 
    // left other of your code as it is.
    }
}
```

And change execution to `new GetJSON().execute();`

Comment: Shouldn't I change the `protected Void doInBackground()` to `protected String doInBackground()`?

Comment: Still nothing is being displayed in the widget :/

Comment: Yes, `protected String doInBackground()`. Try to debug and see if all data were parsed correctly. Do you need to update home screen widgets?

Comment: The home screen widget is not showing anything... the two textviews.

Comment: The Eclipse debugger isn't even firing :/

Comment: Even in `doInBackground()` ?

Comment: I used LOG to see if the information is being pulled... I can see it is being pulled successfully in the `LogCat`

Comment: It's really strange way for coding with the home widget, your views is not updating properlu, because you run AsynkTask for update - it runs in different thread, and then the system runs `appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);` So your AsynkTask have finished after the system update your widget with new data and you don't see any changes. Thinks about this, and rework your widget update logic :)

Comment: I am calling the function before the updateAppWdget. Shouldn't that fix it?

Comment: That's try, but AsynkTask running in different thread, and after executing your AsynkTask the system immediately do this: `appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);`. So the main thread and the AsynkTask run simultaneously, but AsynkTask have finished after the widget update procedure ended :)

Comment: hmmmmm... I tried to get some examples but none I can find. I wonder what would be better...