# Android Widgets - Reset on screen Orientation change

Tags: android, android-widget, widget

I have a widget on screen, a button click on widget enables/disables a broadcast reciver ... But when i turn the phone a bit.. all values on widget get reset and gives wrong info to user... I tried most of things to prevent this as below :

1. added **android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"** in manifest
2. added this method in mainavtivity

   @Override
           public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
               super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
               setContentView(R.layout.widget_layout);
           }
3. I hace also see suggestion to use onSaveInstanceState and all, But I cant get textview data from my widget from remoteviews approach to save it .. any other way

---- HERE IS THE CODE ----------

In Manifest...

```
<receiver android:name="MyWidgetProvider"  >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
                <action android:name="com.makelifesimple.autopickmobiletracker.MyWidgetProvider.ACTION_WIDGET_ACTIVATE"/>
                <action android:name="com.makelifesimple.autopickmobiletracker.MyWidgetProvider.ACTION_WIDGET_DEACTIVATE"/>

           </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/widget_info" />
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name="com.makelifesimple.autopickmobiletracker.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

--- in MyWidgetProvider ---

```
public class MyWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

    public static String ACTION_WIDGET_ACTIVATE = "ActivatePickup";
    public static String ACTION_WIDGET_DEACTIVATE = "DeactivatePickup";


    RemoteViews remoteViews;
  @Override
  public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,int[] appWidgetIds) {

        Toast.makeText(context, "in onupdate", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);

        Intent active = new Intent(context, MyWidgetProvider.class);
        active.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_ACTIVATE);
        PendingIntent actionPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, active, 0);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button1, actionPendingIntent);

        active = new Intent(context, MyWidgetProvider.class);
        active.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_DEACTIVATE);
        actionPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, active, 0);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button2, actionPendingIntent);

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, remoteViews);

  }  

  @Override
  public void onEnabled(Context context){
      Toast.makeText(context, "in enables", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      context.startService(new Intent(context, MyWidgetProvider.class));
  }

  @Override
  public void onDisabled(Context context){
      Toast.makeText(context, "in disable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      context.stopService(new Intent(context, MyWidgetProvider.class));
  }



  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      Toast.makeText(context, "in onRecive", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
     if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_WIDGET_ACTIVATE)) {

          ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, PhoneCallReceiver.class);
          PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
          pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
          //remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.button1,"ACTIVATED");
          remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.textView2,"ACTIVE");

      } else if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_WIDGET_DEACTIVATE)) {

          ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, PhoneCallReceiver.class);
          PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
          pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

          remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.textView2,"INACTIVE");

          Intent headSetUnPluggedintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG);
          headSetUnPluggedintent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_REGISTERED_ONLY);
          headSetUnPluggedintent.putExtra("state", 0); // 0 = unplugged  1 = Headset with microphone 2 = Headset without microphone
          headSetUnPluggedintent.putExtra("name", "Headset");
          context.sendOrderedBroadcast(headSetUnPluggedintent, null);

      } 

        Intent active = new Intent(context, MyWidgetProvider.class);
        active.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_ACTIVATE);
        PendingIntent actionPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, active, 0);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button1, actionPendingIntent);

        active = new Intent(context, MyWidgetProvider.class);
        active.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_DEACTIVATE);
        actionPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, active, 0);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button2, actionPendingIntent);


      ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName( context, MyWidgetProvider.class );
      AppWidgetManager.getInstance( context ).updateAppWidget(thisWidget, remoteViews );

  }

}
```

what am i missing here.......PLS  PLSSSSSSSSSS HELP

Comment: Could you post the key code please? Also, do you mean an AppWidget on the home screen or a button of some sort in an Activity (or something else)?

Comment: i mean a button on widgets... they get automaticaly set back to initial values on orientation change

Comment: Did any of the answers help? If so, you might like to tick and upvote them; if not you could clarify why and we might be able to help more ...

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty risky to rely on `onUpdate` in the widget provider to do more than catch the creation and deleting of the widgets. Everything else should be managed from elsewhere, typically a service, or a thread, started from `onUpdate`.

You then catch orientation change (through various method, whether from an activity or a Broadcast receiver that triggers the service or other thread) which will need to redo the code you have in `onUpdate`.

Other places to look:

- A good tutorial is in: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidWidgets/article.html, I would only quibble with one point in that tutorial: it's generally advised to not use updatePeriod.
- There's a bit more detail in [Who (and how) create an instance of AppWidgetProvider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15665491/who-and-how-create-an-instance-of-appwidgetprovider/15667202#15667202).
- Some thoughts on handling services, activities and widgets all in one app are in [Service being re-Created by AlarmManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15435117/service-being-re-created-by-alarmmanager/15691054#15691054).

Comment: Why the downvote? Please let me know of my error in a comment so I can improve the answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are several errors in this code.

First, your `onEnabled` and `onDisabled` methods try to treat the `AppWidgetProvider` as a service. It isn't: it's a `BroadcastReceiver`, so these calls will fail, possibly terminating your app.

However, this won't happen. You've overridden `onReceive` without calling through to the `super` method, so none of the other methods will be called at all.

Fix these errors before you try to do anything else. Your `onEnabled` and `onDisabled` methods should be empty, and your `onReceive` should look like the following, without the duplicate widget-update code you have there now.

```
if (ACTION_WIDGET_ACTIVATE.equals(intent.getAction()) {
    ...
} else if (ACTION_WIDGET_DEACTIVATE.equals(intent.getAction()) {
    ...
} else {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
}
```

Comment: why is it necessary to implement coding in `onReceive()` ? I have seen plenty of codes most of whom have used the `onEnabled & onDisabled`. Widget is a broadcastReceiver but that doesn't make it necessary to implement all the coding in `onReceive`. If it does, then why are onEnabled and onDeleted methods provided in the `AppWidgetProvider` class? Just to look and do nothing?

Answer (score 0):

As posted here: [After orientation change buttons on a widget are not responding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4574054/after-orientation-change-buttons-on-a-widget-are-not-responding) you can avoid this by applying all widget changes on each update, including button click handlers.

Answer (score -2):

For AppWidgets it is essential to implement `onUpdate` to redraw the widget's content.

Comment: onUpdate is not being called for orientation changes