# Services issue in Android

Tags: android, performance, android-intent, android-service, android-sqlite

i am developing an application in which i want to run Background services for sending data to my java server. i have written code for it and its giving me some error, but i cant figure-out myself where am going wrong. please help me out of this problem and suggest some solution.

I am written send function for it within Intent service where m retrieving data from Sq-Lite DB and stores in String variables.

but i am getting error that

" Only one Looper may be created per thread "

my Service file name is MyService, i have also posted my log cat
please suggest me some solution and thank you...!

**MyService.java**

```
package com.ami.wbs;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;



public class MyService extends Service {
Timer timer=new Timer();
int counter=0;
Socket client,clientSocket;
ServerSocket serverSocket;
String ServerIP = "192.168.43.84";
InputStreamReader inputStreamReader;
BufferedReader bufferedReader;
PrintWriter printwriter;
String data,start,end,code,IMEI,username,result,meter_no = null;
String consumer_name,consumer_id,consumer_add,consumer_meter_no,prev_reading,current_reading,path;
DB_Adapter database;

public void setDB(DB_Adapter db){
    database = db;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "On create in My service..",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    if(timer!=null)
    {
        timer.cancel();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "On destory in My service..",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
    Looper.prepare(); 
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "On start in My service..",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "On start command in My service..",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    dosome();
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
public void dosome()
{

    database = new DB_Adapter(getApplicationContext(), "WBS", null, 1);
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(database.count_consumer())
            {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sending", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                send();
                sendimage();
            }else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "DB is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //onDestroy();

            }

            Log.d("MyService",String.valueOf(counter++));
        }
    },0,5000);
}
public void send()
{

    Log.d("MyService","calling snd()...");
    start = "@STR";
    end = "000$";
    code = "05";
    username = database.get_username();
    consumer_meter_no = database.get_all_consumer_data();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "meter no"+consumer_meter_no, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    current_reading = database.get_current_reading(consumer_meter_no, "CONSUMER");
    String username_padd = username;
    // padding for username
    int fixlen= 10;
    int usernamelen= username.length();

    if(fixlen>usernamelen)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<(fixlen-usernamelen);i++)
        {
            username_padd="*"+username_padd;
        }
    }
    //padding for meter no
    String meter_no_padd = consumer_meter_no;
    int fixlen1= 20;
    int meter_nolen= consumer_meter_no.length();

    if(fixlen1>meter_nolen)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<(fixlen1-meter_nolen);i++)
        {
            meter_no_padd="*"+meter_no_padd;
        }
    }
    //padding for current reading
    String curr_reading_padd = current_reading;
    int fixlen2= 6;
    int cr_readinglen= current_reading.length();

    if(fixlen>cr_readinglen)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<(fixlen2-cr_readinglen);i++)
        {
            curr_reading_padd="0"+curr_reading_padd;
        }
    }

        TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        IMEI = tm.getDeviceId();//imei no is captured
        data = start+code+username_padd+IMEI+meter_no_padd+curr_reading_padd+end;
        try {
            client=new Socket(ServerIP,2222);
            printwriter=new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(),true);
            printwriter.write(data);

            printwriter.flush();
            printwriter.close();
            client.close();

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
public void sendimage()
   {        
        try {
            //image send
            client = new Socket(ServerIP,4444);
            path = database.get_path(consumer_meter_no);
            File file = new File(path);
            byte[] mybytearray = new byte[(int) file.length()];
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
            bis.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
            OutputStream os = client.getOutputStream();
            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(os);     
            dos.writeUTF(file.getName()); 
            os.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
            os.flush();
            bis.close();
            fis.close();
            client.close();

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
   }

   public String receive()
    {
        try {
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "in receive", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(1111);
            clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream());
           bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader); //get the client message
           String  msg = bufferedReader.readLine();
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           String start1= msg.substring(0,4);
           String code1= msg.substring(4, 6);
           String result1= msg.substring(6, 16);
           String end1= msg.substring(16, 20);

           if(start1.equals("@STR") && code1.equals("05") && end1.equals("999$"))
           {
            /*Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), start1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), code1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), end1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/

            result = result1;
            remove_padding();
           }else
           {
            /*Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "in else"+start1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "in else"+code1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "in else"+result1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "in else"+end1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
            result = result1;
            remove_padding();
           }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
    public String remove_padding()
    {
        //String starusername=usernamepasswordIMEI.substring(0,10);

        char star='*';

                int count=0;

                    if(result.charAt(0) == star)
                    {
                        for(int i=0;i<result.length();i++)
                        {

                            if(result.charAt(i) == star)
                            {
                                count++;
                            }
                            /*break;*/
                        }//end for
                        meter_no=result.substring(count,result.length());
                        //return meter_no;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("user name String doesn't start with *");
                        meter_no=result;

                    }

                    ///Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ack Received for metr no:-"+meter_no, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return meter_no;

    }
```

}

**Log Cat**

```
06-24 09:32:02.557: E/AndroidRuntime(895): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-24 09:32:02.557: E/AndroidRuntime(895): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start     service com.ami.wbs.MyService@40e75358 with Intent { cmp=com.ami.wbs/.MyService }:     java.lang.RuntimeException: Only one Looper may be created per thread
06-24 09:32:02.557: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2673)
06-24 09:32:02.557: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:141)
06-24 09:32:02.557: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1331)
06-24 09:32:02.557: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-24 09:32:02.557: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-24 09:32:02.557: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-24 09:32:02.557: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-24 09:32:02.557: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-24 09:32:02.557: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-24 09:32:02.557: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-24 09:32:02.557: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-24 09:32:02.557: E/AndroidRuntime(895): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Only one Looper may be created per thread
06-24 09:32:02.557: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at android.os.Looper.prepare(Looper.java:78)
06-24 09:32:02.557: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at android.os.Looper.prepare(Looper.java:73)
06-24 09:32:02.557: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at com.ami.wbs.MyService.onStart(MyService.java:75)
06-24 09:32:02.557: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at android.app.Service.onStartCommand(Service.java:450)
06-24 09:32:02.557: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at com.ami.wbs.MyService.onStartCommand(MyService.java:85)
06-24 09:32:02.557: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2656)
06-24 09:32:02.557: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  ... 10 more
06-24 09:32:10.015: E/AndroidRuntime(1075): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-24 09:32:10.015: E/AndroidRuntime(1075): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.ami.wbs.MyService@40ce2b78 with Intent { cmp=com.ami.wbs/.MyService }: java.lang.RuntimeException: Only one Looper may be created per thread
06-24 09:32:10.015: E/AndroidRuntime(1075):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2673)
06-24 09:32:10.015: E/AndroidRuntime(1075):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:141)
06-24 09:32:10.015: E/AndroidRuntime(1075):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1331)
06-24 09:32:10.015: E/AndroidRuntime(1075):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-24 09:32:10.015: E/AndroidRuntime(1075):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-24 09:32:10.015: E/AndroidRuntime(1075):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-24 09:32:10.015: E/AndroidRuntime(1075):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-24 09:32:10.015: E/AndroidRuntime(1075):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-24 09:32:10.015: E/AndroidRuntime(1075):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-24 09:32:10.015: E/AndroidRuntime(1075):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-24 09:32:10.015: E/AndroidRuntime(1075):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-24 09:32:10.015: E/AndroidRuntime(1075): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Only one Looper may be created per thread
06-24 09:32:10.015: E/AndroidRuntime(1075):     at android.os.Looper.prepare(Looper.java:78)
06-24 09:32:10.015: E/AndroidRuntime(1075):     at android.os.Looper.prepare(Looper.java:73)
06-24 09:32:10.015: E/AndroidRuntime(1075):     at com.ami.wbs.MyService.onStart(MyService.java:75)
06-24 09:32:10.015: E/AndroidRuntime(1075):     at android.app.Service.onStartCommand(Service.java:450)
06-24 09:32:10.015: E/AndroidRuntime(1075):     at com.ami.wbs.MyService.onStartCommand(MyService.java:85)
06-24 09:32:10.015: E/AndroidRuntime(1075):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2656)
06-24 09:32:10.015: E/AndroidRuntime(1075):     ... 10 more
```

**DB_Adapter**

```
package com.ami.wbs;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DB_Adapter extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public SQLiteDatabase db;
public static final String KEY_NAME = "USERNAME";
public static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "PASSWORD";
public static final String login = "LOGIN";
public static final String consumer = "CONSUMER";
public static final String consumer_xml = "CONSUMER_XML";
public static final String zone="ZONE_DETAILS";
public static final String subzone="SUBZONE_DETAILS";
public static final String image="IMAGE";

public DB_Adapter(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory,
        int version) 
{
    super(context, name, factory, version);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase arg0) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    arg0.execSQL("CREATE TABLE LOGIN(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
            "USERNAME TEXT NOT NULL," +
            "PASSWORD TEXT NOT NULL,"+
            "IMEI INTEGER NOT NULL)");
    arg0.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IMAGE(METER_NO INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL," +
            "PATH TEXT NOT NULL)");
    arg0.execSQL("CREATE TABLE CONSUMER(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
            "CONSUMER_ID INTEGER NOT NULL," +
            "CONSUMER_NAME TEXT NOT NULL,"+
            "CONSUMER_ADDRESS TEXT NOT NULL,"+
            "METER_NO INTEGER NOT NULL," +
            "PREV_READING INTEGER NOT NULL," +
            "CURR_READING INTEGER NOT NULL," +
            "IMAGE TEXT NOT NULL)" 
            );
    arg0.execSQL("CREATE TABLE CONSUMER_XML(METER_NO INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL," +
            "CONSUMER_ID INTEGER NOT NULL," +
            "CONSUMER_NAME TEXT NOT NULL,"+
            "CONSUMER_ADDRESS TEXT NOT NULL,"+
            "PREV_READING INTEGER NOT NULL)");
    arg0.execSQL("CREATE TABLE ZONE_DETAILS(ZONE_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL," +
            "ZONE_NAME TEXT NOT NULL)");
    arg0.execSQL("CREATE TABLE SUBZONE_DETAILS(SUBZONE_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL," +
            "ZONE_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,SUBZONE_NAME TEXT NOT NULL)");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    arg0.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST LOGIN");
    arg0.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST CONSUMER");
    arg0.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST CONSUMER_XML");
    arg0.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST ZONE_DETAILS");
    arg0.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST SUBZONE_DETAILS");
    arg0.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST IMAGE");
    onCreate(arg0);
}
public long signup_detail(String nusername,String npassword,String imei)     // call from Sign Up activity
{
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("USERNAME", nusername);
    cv.put("PASSWORD", npassword);
    cv.put("IMEI", imei);
    db = getWritableDatabase();
    return db.insert("LOGIN", null, cv);
}
public boolean check_Authentication(String username, String password)      // call from Login Activity
{
    Cursor c = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(
            "SELECT USERNAME,PASSWORD FROM " + login + " WHERE "
                    + KEY_NAME + "='" + username +"'AND "+KEY_PASSWORD+"='"+password+"'" ,  null);
   if (c.getCount()>0)
      return true;
      return false;
}
public void sync_delete()                                                  // call from Sync menu option(Home Activity)
{
    db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete("ZONE_DETAILS", null, null);
    db.delete("SUBZONE_DETAILS", null, null);
}
public void clear()                                                        // call from Clear menu option (Home Activity)
{
    db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete("ZONE_DETAILS", null, null);
    db.delete("SUBZONE_DETAILS", null, null);
    db.delete("CONSUMER", null, null);
    db.delete("CONSUMER_XML", null, null);
}
public void forget_password(String username,String password,String imei)  // call from Forgot Password Activity
{
    String [] args = {username};
    db = getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("PASSWORD", password);
    cv.put("IMEI", imei);
    db.update("LOGIN", cv, "USERNAME" + "=?", args);
}
public void set_path(String meter_no,String path)                       // call to save path
{
    db=getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
    cv.put("METER_NO", meter_no);
    cv.put("PATH", path);
    db.insert(image, null, cv);
}
public void addZone(String zone_id,String zone_name)                      // call from Sync menu option(Home Activity) to add zone details
{
    db=getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
    cv.put("ZONE_ID", zone_id);
    cv.put("ZONE_NAME", zone_name);
    db.insert(zone, null, cv);
}
public void addSubZone(String subzone_id,String zone_id,String subzone_name) // call from Sync menu option(Home Activity) to add subzone details
{
    db=getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
    cv.put("SUBZONE_ID", subzone_id);
    cv.put("ZONE_ID", zone_id);
    cv.put("SUBZONE_NAME", subzone_name);
    db.insert(subzone, null, cv);
}
public void addConsumer_details(String meter,String consumer_id,String consumer_name,String consumer_add,String pr)
{                                                                           // call from get list button (Home Activity)
    db=getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
    cv.put("METER_NO", meter);
    cv.put("CONSUMER_ID", consumer_id);
    cv.put("CONSUMER_NAME", consumer_name);
    cv.put("CONSUMER_ADDRESS", consumer_add);
    cv.put("PREV_READING", pr);
    db.insert(consumer_xml, null, cv);
}
public void addReading_details(String cid,String cname,String cadd,String mno,String pr,String cr,String path)
{                                                                           // call from Reading details Activity on Save button
    db=getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
    cv.put("CONSUMER_ID", cid);
    cv.put("CONSUMER_NAME", cname);
    cv.put("CONSUMER_ADDRESS", cadd);
    cv.put("METER_NO", mno);
    cv.put("PREV_READING", pr);
    cv.put("CURR_READING", cr);
    cv.put("IMAGE", path);
    db.insert(consumer, null, cv);
}
public void delete_consumer(String mtrno)                                   // call from Reading details,on Save button
{
    String [] args ={mtrno};
    db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(consumer_xml, "METER_NO" + "=?", args);
}
public boolean count_list_of_consumer()                                     // call from Login activity
{
    Cursor c = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT METER_NO FROM " + consumer_xml,null);
    if (c.getCount()>0)
          return true;
          return false;
}
public boolean count_consumer()                                     // used in services
{
    Cursor c = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT METER_NO FROM " + consumer,null);
    if (c.getCount()>0)
          return true;
          return false;
}
public String get_consumer_id(String mtrno,String table)                            // call to get consumer id
{
    String cid = null;
    Cursor c = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("Select * from " + table, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    do
    {
        String meter_no=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("METER_NO"));

        if(meter_no.equals(mtrno))
        {
            cid=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("CONSUMER_ID"));
        }
    }while(c.moveToNext());
    return cid;
}
public String get_path(String mtrno)                            // call to get consumer id
{

    String path = null;
    Cursor c = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("Select * from IMAGE" , null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    do
    {
        String meter_no=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("METER_NO"));

        if(meter_no.equals(mtrno))
        {
            path=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("PATH"));
            return path;
        }
    }while(c.moveToNext());
    return path;
}
public String get_consumer_name(String mtrno,String table)                      // call to get consumer name
{
    String cname=null;
    Cursor c = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("Select * from " + table, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    do
    {
        String meter_no=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("METER_NO"));

        if(meter_no.equals(mtrno))
        {
            cname=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("CONSUMER_NAME"));                
        }
    }while(c.moveToNext());     
    return cname;
}
public String get_consumer_address(String mtrno,String table)               // call to get consumer address
{
    String cadd=null;
    Cursor c = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("Select * from " + table, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    do
    {
        String meter_no=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("METER_NO"));

        if(meter_no.equals(mtrno))
        {
            cadd=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("CONSUMER_ADDRESS"));
        }
    }while(c.moveToNext());     
    return cadd;
}
public String get_previous_reading(String mtrno,String table)                   // call to get consumer prev reading
{
    String cpr=null;
    Cursor c = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("Select * from " + table, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    do
    {
        String meter_no=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("METER_NO"));

        if(meter_no.equals(mtrno))
        {
            cpr=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("PREV_READING"));
        }
    }while(c.moveToNext());
    return cpr;
}
public String get_current_reading(String mtrno,String table)                                // call to get consumer current reading
{
    String ccr=null;
    Cursor c = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("Select * from " + table, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    do
    {
        String meter_no=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("METER_NO"));

        if(meter_no.equals(mtrno))
        {
            ccr=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("CURR_READING"));
        }
    }while(c.moveToNext());
    return ccr;
}
public ArrayList<String> get_meter_id(String table)                             // call to get list of meter numbers
{
    ArrayList<String>c_meter_id=new ArrayList<String>();
    Cursor c = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("Select METER_NO from " + table, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    do
    {
        String s1=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("METER_NO"));
        c_meter_id.add(s1);
    }while(c.moveToNext());
    return c_meter_id;
}
public ArrayList<String> get_cid(String table)                              // call to get list of consumer numbers
{
    ArrayList<String>c_meter_id=new ArrayList<String>();
    Cursor c = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("Select CONSUMER_ID from " + table, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    do
    {
        String s1=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("CONSUMER_ID"));
        c_meter_id.add(s1);
    }while(c.moveToNext());
    return c_meter_id;
}
public ArrayList<String> get_zone_name()                                // call to get list of zone list
{
    ArrayList<String>zn=new ArrayList<String>();
    Cursor c = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("Select ZONE_NAME from " + zone, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    do
    {
        String s1=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("ZONE_NAME"));
        zn.add(s1);
    }while(c.moveToNext());
    return zn;
}

public ArrayList<String> get_subzone_name(String zone_name)             // call to get list of subzone
{
    SQLiteDatabase db=getReadableDatabase();
    String s;
    Cursor c1=db.rawQuery("SELECT ZONE_ID FROM "+ zone +" WHERE ZONE_NAME='"+zone_name+"'",null);
    c1.moveToFirst();//find first value
    do{
        s=c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("ZONE_ID"));   
    }
    while(c1.moveToNext());//find first pos to next pos
    int zone_id=Integer.parseInt(s);
    ArrayList<String>szn=new ArrayList<String>();
    c1=db.rawQuery("SELECT SUBZONE_NAME FROM "+ subzone +" WHERE ZONE_ID='"+zone_id+"'",null);
    c1.moveToFirst();
    do
    {
        String s1=c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("SUBZONE_NAME"));
        szn.add(s1);
    }while(c1.moveToNext());
    return szn;
}

public String get_subzone_id(String sub_zone_name)              // call to get subzone id
{
    SQLiteDatabase db=getReadableDatabase();
    String sz_id;
    Cursor c2=db.rawQuery("SELECT SUBZONE_ID FROM "+ subzone +" WHERE SUBZONE_NAME='"+sub_zone_name+"'",null);
    c2.moveToFirst();
    do
    {
        sz_id=c2.getString(c2.getColumnIndex("SUBZONE_ID"));
    }while(c2.moveToNext());
    return sz_id;
}
public String get_username()                            // call to get Username
{
    SQLiteDatabase db=getReadableDatabase();
    String user_name;
    Cursor c2=db.rawQuery("SELECT USERNAME FROM "+ login,null);
    c2.moveToFirst();
    do
    {
        user_name=c2.getString(c2.getColumnIndex("USERNAME"));
    }while(c2.moveToNext());
    return user_name;
}
public String get_all_consumer_data()                           // used in service
{

    Cursor c = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("Select * from CONSUMER" , null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    String meter_no=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("METER_NO"));
    return meter_no;
}
```

}

@ Neil I have used your structure and called dosome from haldelestartIntent and getting below errors:

```
06-24 10:34:26.615: E/Trace(830): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
06-24 10:38:39.613: E/AndroidRuntime(830): FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-1
06-24 10:38:39.613: E/AndroidRuntime(830): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
06-24 10:38:39.613: E/AndroidRuntime(830):  at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:197)
06-24 10:38:39.613: E/AndroidRuntime(830):  at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:111)
06-24 10:38:39.613: E/AndroidRuntime(830):  at android.widget.Toast$TN.<init>(Toast.java:324)
06-24 10:38:39.613: E/AndroidRuntime(830):  at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:91)
06-24 10:38:39.613: E/AndroidRuntime(830):  at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:238)
06-24 10:38:39.613: E/AndroidRuntime(830):  at com.ami.wbs.MyService$1.run(MyService.java:117)
06-24 10:38:39.613: E/AndroidRuntime(830):  at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
06-24 10:38:50.314: E/Trace(924): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
06-24 10:38:50.864: E/AndroidRuntime(924): FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0
06-24 10:38:50.864: E/AndroidRuntime(924): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
06-24 10:38:50.864: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:197)
06-24 10:38:50.864: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:111)
06-24 10:38:50.864: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at android.widget.Toast$TN.<init>(Toast.java:324)
06-24 10:38:50.864: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:91)
06-24 10:38:50.864: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:238)
06-24 10:38:50.864: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at com.ami.wbs.MyService$1.run(MyService.java:117)
06-24 10:38:50.864: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
```

Comment: I am also using some kind of service. there is no onStart(Intent intent, int startId) part in my code, and it works like charm. besides, Looper.start() seemed suspicious to me.

Answer (score 0):

I have had various challenges with `Service`s and I put together a Question and Answer which covers various things: [Service being re-Created by AlarmManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15435117/service-being-re-created-by-alarmmanager).

In your particular case, I suspect that the issue is that, by putting `super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);` in `onStartCommand` you will then also call `onStart`, meaning that some internal things are done twice. Assuming you need the `Looper`, a better structure is:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    handleStartIntent(intent, flags, startId);
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    handleStartIntent(intent, 0, startId);
}

private void handleStartIntent(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // Ensure this thread has a looper if it doesn't already
    if (Looper.myLooper() == null) Looper.prepare();

    //Your code
    dosome();
}
```

The other issue is your use of `Toast` from within the `Runnable` you are creating to be run on a regular basis. It would be better to replace all of the `Toast` statements with `Log` calls as these do not require access to the UI, and will show up in the logcat.

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention one more thing in my question if i remove my database part from this code and gives hard code values this service is working absolutely fine... is there any problem the way i am retrieving values from database or else?

Comment: i was written my send function code directly in dosome method instead of write it in separate method den it works fine. but m passing values directly hard coded not retrieving from DB

Comment: i tried your given structure for services and its giving me error java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Comment: If you use my structure, and just put `dosome()` in `handleStartIntent`, where are you getting the error - which line? that would help clarify what's going on.

Comment: yes i hv dine same thing that dosome calling from haldleStartIntent

Comment: Updated answer. Be sure not to call `Looper.prepare()` again in the code.

Comment: sorry i have not tried yet. i will try it n den tell you thank you

Comment: Which problem, the first logcat, the second, or a different again?

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

I think you have missed to declare service in your AndroidMainfest.xml

Like `<service > .... </service>`

Comment: i have already written this code in my android mainfest.xml file